# Primefaces : fileUpload display Facesmessage not working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I 'm using Primefaces to upload a picture, I want to check if the picture is not toomal but the file uploadListener only check the maxium size.
I've managed to check the size of the file but I cant display any message.

What can I do?

```
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
        <h:panelGroup>
        <p:fileUpload id="previous" mode="advanced" auto="true"
        fileUploadListener="#{carView.handleImageUpload}"
        dragDropSupport="false" multiple="false" sizeLimit="200000"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" update="form"
        style="position: absolute; right: -1.5%;" label="">


</p:fileUpload>
```

And this a summarized carView

```
public void handleImageUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    ....
        try {

            if (width <=130 || height <=120) {
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "file too small"));
     }
```

FacesMessage is never displayed.

Comment: Did you debug handleImageUpload method? Does it really execute the code where the FacesMessage is created?

Comment: Yes it does execute the code

Answer (score 0):

Actually for some reasons, it was only a CSS issue. A good to way to solve quickly this issue would have been to check if the message I wanted to display was in the html code